# How to switch between x32 and x64 applications in Goland?

Tags: go, x86, 64-bit, goland

I use Goland v. 2020.1 and want to compile x32 and x64 Windows versions of my program. How i can do it?

Comment: Cross-compilation is using `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables when calling `go build`, or using a cross-compilation tool like [gox](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to ask about how to set GOOS and GOARCH in GoLand.
On build configuration there is Environment setting and Program arguments for build tags if you using go build directive.

[image: Refer image]

Comment: Note: [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) - if this is a real image from something you've tested yourself that actually works, that's great.  But the phrasing looks like it's from the ChatGPT AI, which a lot of people have been using recently to post garbage answers without checking that they make sense for the question.  So people are extra suspicious right now, with no way to differentiate between good use of the AI (as a starting point for an answer, or one you've tested and verified) vs. throwing spaghetti at the wall to fool people into upvoting.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I captured the image from my computer and removed some privacy information setting. So I guess I'm not violate the policy.